# Change all but first ',' to "<COMMA>" for each row in file (bash)

Tags: text-processing, csv, tr

I am using bash and have a csv file (dat.csv) that needs to be only two columns (App, Blurb) of data but due to many ',' on each row it is becoming MANY columns.

EXAMPLE OF PROBLEM csv.dat:

```
 App , Blurb
 diff, this is the diff program, bla bla bla, yadda yadda
 word, this is ms product, it is not very good, I dont like it
 dd, this is a Linux disk application , its awesome!, bla bla, ttly
 ...
```

The problem I am having is that because the 'Blurb' col has additional ',' the data is getting piped into subsequent columns (c, d, etc) of the dat.csv file.

THE GOAL is to have all but the first ',' from every row be changed to "COMMA" so all the 'Blurb' data remains in col B.

E.g. DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
 App, Blurb                 
 diff, this is the diff program<COMMMA> bla bla bla<COMMA> yadda yadda
 word, this is ms product<COMMA> it is not very good<COMMA> I dont like it
 dd, this is a Linux disk application <COMMA> its awesome!<COMMA>bla bla<COMMA> ttly
 ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Bash isn't a text editor; you just need something you can run from the command-line, yes?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "bash script". thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/,/<COMMA>/2g' infile
```

Or portability:

```
sed 's/,/<COMMA>/g; s/<COMMA>/,/' infile
```

Comment: [GNU sed docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command): "Only replace the numberth match of the regexp.

interaction in s command Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the numberth, and then match and replace all matches from the numberth on."

Comment: @afshin In case the string "<COMMA>" were to exist in the first field, that is to say, before the first "," then the portable sed code would disturb the first field.

Comment: @RakeshSharma that's an exception, which can be modified to `sed 's/,/something-Uniq/; s/,/<COMMA>/g; s/something-Uniq/,/' infile` with another exception that `something-Uniq` never be occur in the input file where you had the same answer about this.

Comment: @afshin Now the  problem has been transferred to `something-uniq`. what if it too is already sitting there before the first `,` ?  This `something-uniq` can only be a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can put quotes around the fields, which should tell csv parsers that the commas inside are not field separators:

```
sed 's/"/""/g;                         # escape existing " as ""
     s/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/","/; # replace the first , and the
                                       # whitespace around it with ","

     s/^[[:space:]]*/"/;               # add a " at the start (and
                                       # get rid of whitespace there)

     s/[[:space:]]*$/"/;               # same at the end'
```

Comment: @Stephane_Chazelas Some commenting is in order here to indicate the flow of events going on.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it **POSIX**-*ly* as follows:

```
sed -e '
    y/,/\n/          ;# change all commas to newlines, which are guaranteed to not be there
    s/\n/,/          ;# then change the first of those newlines to a comma, i.e., restore
    s//<COMMA>/g     ;# and all the remaining newline(s) change to <COMMA>
' dat.csv
```